# Is it possible to clean up overlapping faces?

Tags: workflow, faces

I've been using the Boolean Modifier to union multiple meshes, but it often makes overlapping faces, that are criss-crossing each other, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Is there any way that I can remove the unnecessary faces?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can dissolve those faces by hitting X on your keyboard and then Dissolve Faces:

[image]

Comment: Seems to work, but since the mesh has gotten probably over 100 of these overlaps, is there a way to do em all at once?

Answer (score 1):

Enter in edit mode, select All with <kbd>A</kbd> Use Mesh>CleanUp>MergebyDistance
[image]

Comment: I've tried that, but since the four overlapping faces are sharing the same 4 corner vertices, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Also there's an addon called  3D print Toolbox, that might help you with overlapping vertices and Edges and faces. Add it, then select your model and click on make manifold, and see if that cleans up your topology.  https://ibb.co/KhFMRbv

Comment: Can you share the file to check?

Comment: The 3D Print Tool doesn't seem to do it either, it reduced the mesh to just only a few random faces; https://i.gyazo.com/fdb85d201677f7d2f5b73ba4d28831b7.gif

And is there a way to easily share the blender file on via this forum?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/